# Address Bar of PopUp Window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am making an online exam. The exam proper is in a popup window (to avoid opening new tabs for research). The problem is in the popup window. When I reload (highlighting the address in the address bar and press enter), my timer resets and other data will change. Is there a way to avoid reloading the popup window?

Comment: A lot of information are missing to help you.
Why you reload the page? is intentional or accidental? When you talk about popup you mean window of browser without address bar?

Comment: Yes sir. Is it possible? Or is there a method to avoid clicking/highlighting the address in the address bar. Intentional.

Comment: One can not stop user refreshing the page. You can store some data in cookie/session if you only care about data loss

Comment: So now is clear, you want to avoid students to refresh the popup. is that right?

Comment: @SirAndreaBogazzi: Yes even if I don't know if they will intentionally or accidentally refresh the page by doing the method I mention above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer from @Murali i would suggest:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { 
return confirm('Do you really whant to add +1 to you reset counter and -1 to your final exam evaluation?' };
```

And then , if you are using php (any other server language still apply ) :

```
<?php
// in your popup page //
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["load_count"])){
    $_SESSION["load_count"]=0;
} else {
    $_SESSION["load_count"]+=1;
}
?>
```

...

in the html part

```
<?php echo "you currently reloaded the page ".$_SESSION["load_count"]." times"; ?>
```

it doesn't block them to refresh, but better than nothing.

You can also try:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { return false; };
```

but remember if students are normal people they can use browser console and terminate any javascript by themselves.

For that reason, if your timer logic is in javascript, you are not completely safe.

Comment: I see. The first suggestion is kinda great, I think I will apply it. Thank you so much for a big help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the user to confirm to reload using [`onbeforeunload event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload). But i dont think you can prevent browser built in functions

try

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function () { return confirm('Are you sure?' };
```